# Apache 2.4 Ubuntu access denied for cgi-bin

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, cgi

I have the following apache configuration:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
      AllowOverride None
      AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl 
      Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Inside `/var/www/cgi-bin` I have the file:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  288 Jan 23 14:29 test.pl*
```

The file has valid perl script that is being launched when I execute it directly. But when I try to run it as cgi:

```
$wget http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/test.pl
```

I get `ERROR 403: Forbidden`. The following line is added to the error log:

```
[Sat Jan 23 15:42:44.655000 2016] [authz_core:error]
[pid 1751:tid 140567392528128] [client 127.0.0.1:34927] 
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/cgi-bintest.pl
```

For some reason there is no slash `cgi-bintest.pl`. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the missing slash at the end:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
```